# How to set the left margin in WPF application using VB.NET?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How can I set the left margin in a WPF application to 213 pixels?

I have tried:

```
MyRecatgle.Margin.left = 213
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
MyRecatgle.Margin = New Thickness(213, 0, 0, 0)
```

Where the constructor parameters for Thickness are:

```
Thickness(left, top, right, bottom)
```